# How can I test for an ActiveX control without using new ActiveXObject()?

Tags: javascript, activex

Is there a way to test for the presence of an ActiveX control (with JavaScript) without actually attempting to create an object from it?  The control I'm attempting to detect is taking a long time to instantiate; I'm just looking for a more efficient approach, if there is one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way - some special event from AX control informing you that all initialize actions are done.

If you have control's sources - you can do it easily. Otherwise you deal with a black box and there is no **reliable** way to know that init is done.